# Android Marketplace API

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know if android marketplace has on api/feed to access information about their apps(title,summary,icon,version,etc...)?  My goal is to maintain my own database of android apps.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know if android marketplace has on api/feed to access information about their apps(title,summary,icon,version,etc...)?

There is no official API or feed available at this time. We have requested it, without results to date.

Answer (score 0):

They don't have a nice, simple SOAP API but you can access their data with ProtoBuf.  Here's an API library for Java the implements most of the functionality for you: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/  They also share links to a view different ports for different languages.

Comment: This is not authorized, let alone supported, by Google. Use of this library or its ports may result in legal action.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Yes, this is true, but it's still the **only way** to access the data at this time. Many sites that list Android apps are using this same exact method to get their data. This is also being used in anti-piracy libraries to check if the user purchased an application. So although its not officially supported or sanctioned, it's the only method to accomplish that task. If you do decide to use this, **proceed at your own risk**, even though I haven't heard of any legal issues surrounding this.

Comment: "but it's still the only way to access the data at this time" -- that does not make it legitimate. "This is also being used in anti-piracy libraries to check if the user purchased an application." -- committing piracy for anti-piracy reasons is ironic. "even though I haven't heard of any legal issues surrounding this" -- you haven't been talking to the right people. Don't get me wrong, this data should be available, and I have personally lobbied for it to be made available. The fact is, it is not available and legitimate attempts to license it have failed.