# Get current version of App from Google Play Store

Tags: c#, google-play

if I want to request what version an app on the play store is at, is there some sort of endpoint I can request to? I know iOS/App store has one, but I've been unable to find one for Android/Google.

To be clear, I want to retrieve a string, probably similar to this: "X.X.X"., where it represents the current version of the app.

Edit:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051569/android-marketplace-api) was suggested, however, the most upvoted answer is from 2011, and the second answer is a Java API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Marketplace API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051569/android-marketplace-api)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have updated my question.